# On ReactJS Native for an Apple Watch, how can I set a static image to be displayed for the WatchKit and Glances?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-glances

If I have an image foo.png, how can I set it to be displayed for the WatchKit and Glances for a ReactJS Native application on the Apple Watch?

How can it be done (if it can be done) purely from ReactJS Native?

If it needs to be done via ReactJS talking to Objective-C, what should I be reading for that?

Thanks,

--UPDATE--

I've learned that ReactJS Native does not run directly on Apple Watch.

**So I'd like to know how to display an image, centered / transformed / ..., using Objective-C.**

Answer (score 1):

The best way to display an image in a WatchKit-App is to use a WKInterfaceImage with a UIImage. Check [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/) for more details.